# JQuery Mobile add <div> using .append

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add `<div><ul><li>` using the .append method. Not having any luck!

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="calendar" data-add-back-btn="true">

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" id="myBlank">   
        <!-- CONTENT -->    
    </div>

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>-CALENDAR-</h1>
         <a class="ui-btn-right" id="infoButton" onclick="getMyCalendar();">Refresh</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" id="calToday">  
        <!-- CONTENT -->    
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

Problem is in the following?

```
$('#calendar').append('<div data-role="content" id="month"><ul data-role="listview"><li>HI</li></ul></div>');
```

UPDATE:
here is my code, the problem is where to init the page again since it's populating prior to page load :

```
    $.post(jaction, { device: "stdbrowser", action: "doLogin", j_username: xuser, j_password: xpwd, j_accessCode: xcode, j_host: jaction }, function(data) {

        var jsessionid = sessionStorage.jsid;
        var prefix = sessionStorage.jsid_prefix;
        var doAction = "https://" + prefix + ".domain.net/servlet/ServletController;jsessionid=" + jsessionid + "?action=" + action;

        $.get(doAction, function(data) {
        var iDivFormat = formatCalendar(data);

        $('#calendar').append('<div data-role="content" id="month"><ul data-role="listview"><li>HI</li></ul></div>').children().last().trigger("create");       
        $('#month').html(iDivFormat).trigger("pagecreate");;
        $('#calendar #progress').remove();
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What isn't working? http://jsfiddle.net/wtTn6/

Comment: like your example I'm getting the standard <li> tag not the JQMobile formatted look?

Comment: Check-out my answer below.

Comment: After you append the items, call `$('id').listview();` or `.listview().listview('refresh');`

Comment: not sure why since the page is not loaded yet?

Comment: You bind it to which event? Pageinit, pagebeforecreate etc...?

Comment: ok, closer but still not desired results, still getting standard <li> - Here is code: `$('#calendar').append('<div data-role="content" id="month"></div>').trigger("create");  
   $('#month').html(iDivFormat).trigger("create");
   $('#calendar').children().trigger("create"); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your list to be look like a jQuery Mobile list-view, you'll need to initialize it:

```
$('#calendar').append('<div data-role="content" id="month"><ul data-role="listview"><li>HI</li></ul></div>').children().last().trigger("create");
```

This code initializes the new `data-role=[content]` element, which in turn initializes the list-view widget nested within.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wtTn6/1/

Comment: Thanks for the example, I'm trying your example but still no luck... Looks like I need to read up on initializing to see where I'm going wrong. Your example is exactly what I'm looking for, just not working for me...

Comment: @BarclayVision No code was included in your comment, I recommend setting-up a JSFiddle of your code, it's a lot easier to digest. My guess is that this is a timing issue for you.

Comment: can't reproduce on JSFiddle, using cross domain ajax that works on safari browser - added update above...